# How to fix "Invalid attempt to read when reader is closed vb.net"

Tags: vb.net

invalid attempt to read when reader is closed error. vb.net

I have the code below that I use to login into MySQL but it keeps displaying the error 'invalid attempt to read when reader is closed' and then it logs in. I don't understand what could still be wrong with the code. Kindly assist, it's so frustrating. Thanks.

```
 Try
    ConnDB()
    command = con.CreateCommand()
    command.CommandText = "SELECT UserName,Password,Type,EmpNo FROM userstable where UserName=@d1 and Password=@d2 and Active='Yes'"
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", txtUsername.Text)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", txtPassword.Text)
    Reader = command.ExecuteReader()
    If Reader.Read = True Then
        ComboBox1.Text = Reader.GetValue(2)
        lblUser.Text = Reader.GetValue(3)
    End If
    If (Reader IsNot Nothing) Then
        Reader.Close()
    End If
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        con.Close()
    End If
    If ComboBox1.Text.Length > 0 Then
        MainMenu.lblUserName.Text = Me.txtUsername.Text
        MainMenu.lblType.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Text
        MainMenu.lblOccupation.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Text
        MainMenu.lblUser.Text = Me.lblUser.Text
        Dim st As String = "Successfully logged in"
        LogFunc(txtUsername.Text, st)
        Me.Hide()
        MainMenu.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Incorrect username or password..Login is Failed...Try again !", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Login")
        txtUsername.SelectAll()
        txtPassword.SelectAll()
        txtUsername.Focus()
        txtPassword.Text = ""
    End If
    command.Dispose()
    ' Reader.Close()
    'command.Dispose()
    con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
Finally
    DisconnMy()
End Try
```

I expect it to log in successfully without displaying the error.

Sorry, I forgot to add this for my connection string.

```
Public Sub ConnDB()
       con.Close()
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Server = '" & ServerMySQL & "';  " _
                               & "Port = '" & PortMySQL & "'; " _
                               & "Database = '" & DBNameMySQL & "'; " _
                               & "user id = '" & UserNameMySQL & "'; " _
                               & "password = '" & PwdMySQL & "'"
        con.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("The system failed to establish a connection", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Database Settings")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you open the connection?

Comment: i have a public sub in my module called ConnDB()

Comment: Why you don't show it? In general it's not a good idea to use a "global", single connection for everything. Note that connection-pooling is enabled by default which means that .NET will take care of the physical connections. So you should create,open,use and close/dispose the connection where you use it.

Comment: I have added it to my question just now

Comment: Public Sub DisconnMy()
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
        command.Dispose()
    End Sub.  I have used this to close all my connections everytime i open it

Comment: @NickOsoo - Don't use field-level variables for `con` and `command`. That's just asking for trouble. Only ever let those be created and used in each method.

Comment: Also, don't do `Catch ex As Exception` - you should only ever catch **specific exceptions** that you can **meaningfully handle**.

Answer (score 2):

In general it's not a good idea to use a "global", single connection for everything. Note that [connection-pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) is enabled by default which means that .NET will take care of the physical connections. So you should create,open,use and close/dispose the connection where you use it.

I'm pretty sure that this will fix the issue:

```
Try
    Using con As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(MySettings.Default.SqlConnection)
        Using command = con.CreateCommand()
            command.CommandText = "SELECT UserName,Password,Type,EmpNo FROM userstable where UserName=@d1 and Password=@d2 and Active='Yes'"
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", txtUsername.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", txtPassword.Text)
            con.Open()
            Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.Read() Then
                    ComboBox1.Text = reader.GetValue(2)
                    lblUser.Text = reader.GetValue(3)
                End If
                ' NOTE: you dont need to close the reader/command/connection 
                ' if you use the Using-statement, it will use Dispose even in case of an error
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try
```

Comment: It's showing this notification that ' MySettings is not declared, it may be inaccessible due to its protection level.'

Comment: @NickOsoo: yes, sure, because you don't store the connection string in the settings file(a config file is recommended). I just didn't want to copy your connection string. You can provide a method `GetConnectionString` and call that.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
        <add name="EXPAcademy.My.MySettings.oppsdatabaseConnectionString"
            connectionString="server=192.168.0.100;user id=expserver;password=rodimusprime;database=oppsdatabase;persistsecurityinfo=True"
            providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>.. I have the above connection string in my app.config,i have tried to change MySettings.Default.SqlConnection to oppsdatabaseConnectionString but still shows me Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL host